# Make it easy to add another job to the top of Experience section

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I would expect a “New” next to the “Remove” and “Move Down” on the bar above the top item in the experience section.

(I has just taken me 5 minutes to find it at the bottom of the page, but I always put the most recent job at the top of my cv)

I then had to "press" move up lots of time to get my current job to the top of the list.

Also when you move a job up/down, the window should scroll to keep the **moved job in the centre** (with it's bar visible), otherwise you have to press “move up” then scroll the web browser to re-find the job you have just moved.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the changes you propose, and suspect the current interface comes from the SO interface - answers provided at the bottom and float up as they are 'voted' up.

Careers should have a different use case, which would require looking at the user interface from a fresh slate.

However, code re-use, and the expected user base's existing expectations may mean it makes sense to keep some of the current interface intact, so perhaps not a completely clean slate, but certainly a refreshing view should be taken.